# CSS @import conditional statement

Tags: css, sharepoint, import

I know you can import files to css but can you use conditional logic to determine if you need to load it?

I am wanting to do something like check the url of the page to determine to load it or not. I am doing it in SharePoint and don't have access to SharePoint Server. Just Designer, so I would probably need to do it in the CSS, and it looks like I may not be able to. I am using CSS 3, which has some conditional statements that I am currently looking into.

Comment: No, CSS doesn't understand logical arguments. You need SASS, SCSS or LESS to do something like that.

Comment: i think you will requires `JS` to get the `url` of page not possible with `css` alone